# Boldface Doesn't Work On Beamer. What's Wrong?

Tags: miktex, bold

The \bf command doesn't work in Beamer documents for me. Here's a minimal example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$\bf{R}$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The output is a "R" that is normal, not bolded. However, when I change the class to article, it works.

Does anyone know what's wrong? I'm using Miktex 4.0.1 on Windows. I also have another computer with Miktex 2.9, where it works. Is there something wrong with my Miktex installation?

Comment: `\bf` is a deprecated command, `article` still defines it but maybe `beamer` doesn't any more (I don't know as I have never used `\bf` in my life as I started TeXing 15 years ago). Use `\mathbf` (or `\bm` with the `bm` package) and be happy.

Comment: `\bf`  has not been defined by default in latex since 1994, but when it is defined for compatibility the syntax is `{\bf R}` not `\bf{R}` but also you need to have available a matching bold math version defined which may nor be the case here.

Comment: @campa It doesn't work. I've tried \mathbf{R} and {\bf R}, and I've tried loading the AMS packages. \bm works, but that's not the same as \bf. \bm italicizes the bold, whereas \bf doesn't. I think there may be a problem with the installation.

Comment: Well, it's not that `\bm` italicizes letters, it is rather `\(math)bf` which replaces them by the upright font. But apart from this in a standard setup `\mathbf{R}` will work, so something with your system does indeed seem off. Does the `log` file complain about missing fonts?

Comment: @campa On my up to date TL20 it complains about missing fonts even with `[T1]{fontenc}`. I'd recommend using `\usepackage{sansmathfonts}`, IMO it gives better sans serif fonts for beamer. And for example maps `\mathrm` to `\mathsf` so it does not give seriffed fonts.

Comment: @campa. Ahh, yes, it does. "Font shape 'OT1/cmss/b/n' undefined(Font) using 'OT1/cmss/m/n' instead
Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted." How to fix?

Comment: This is quite strange, on TeXLive 2017 `$\mathbf{R}$` worked pk, and on TeXLive 2020 it substituted it with `sf`. Hmmm....

Comment: @UlrikeFischer proposed a workaround here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55695847#55695847

Comment: @Rmano That works. Also using \usepackage{lmodern} also fixes the problem. But, yes, this appears to be a problem with new versions, whereas older versions seem to be fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beamer: bold math no longer working](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565069/beamer-bold-math-no-longer-working)