# Inactive \bfdefault

Tags: bold, texlive-2020

Yesterday I was forced to reinstall TeXLive on my computer to the newest version 2020.
However, when compiling with pdflatex, I did not get the same results as with the 2018 version.

For example, `\renewcommand\bfdefault{b}` does not seem to have any effect. Is there a simple way how to achieve the original effect of `\renewcommand\bfdefault{b}`?

I know that there is a mention about this issue in https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews31.pdf. As far as I understand, the local change can be achieved by typing `\fontseries{b}\selectfont`. However, I would like to make a global switch so that the bold font in the entire document is typeset in the non-extended bold version.

Minimal (non-)working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand\bfdefault{b}
\listfiles   % as suggested in the comments below

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
abcd \textbf{ABCd}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

.log file

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.2.26)  27 FEB 2021 12:38
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-03-06>
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count167
\c@section=\count168
\c@subsection=\count169
\c@subsubsection=\count170
\c@paragraph=\count171
\c@subparagraph=\count172
\c@figure=\count173
\c@table=\count174
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2018/08/11 v1.3c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks15
\inpenc@posthook=\toks16
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2020/02/11 v2.0o Standard LaTeX package
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/lmodern.sty
Package: lmodern 2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/lmr/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/lmm/m/it on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/lmsy/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/b/it --> OML/lmm/b/it on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> OMS/lmsy/b/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/lmss/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/lmr/m/it on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> OT1/lmss/bx/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> OT1/lmr/bx/it on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 38.
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def
File: l3backend-pdfmode.def 2020-03-12 L3 backend support: PDF mode
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count175
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box45
)
(./test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+lmr on input line 10
.
 (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd
File: t1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
) [1

{c:/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux)

 *File List*
 article.cls    2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
inputenc.sty    2018/08/11 v1.3c Input encoding file
 fontenc.sty
 lmodern.sty    2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
l3backend-pdfmode.def    2020-03-12 L3 backend support: PDF mode
   t1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 ***********

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 646 strings out of 480608
 9165 string characters out of 5907536
 239604 words of memory out of 5000000
 16604 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 539086 words of font info for 27 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 25i,4n,24p,159b,97s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
{c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-ec.enc}<c:/texlive/2020/tex
mf-dist/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmbx10.pfb><c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type
1/public/lm/lmr10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 41142 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 17 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 11 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Not a font expert, but could this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565069/beamer-bold-math-no-longer-working be related? Also https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/630

Comment: I find no problem: I get the non-extended version as expected. Would you please add `\listfiles` in the preamble and show the corresponding output?

Comment: @campa: Updated.

Comment: @campa: Thank you for your feedback. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Erm, sorry, I got my dates mixed: my format version is also newer than yours. I was confused by  the `patch level` number, but you have 2020-02-02 and I've got 2020-10-01. I guess the bottom line is that your distribution is not really up-to-date.

Comment: @campa: I downloaded the file `texlive.iso` from https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-iso.html by selecting 'download from a nearby CTAN mirror'. The file specification at the mirror site is '2020-04-06 15:39   3.7G' which seems to be up-to-date.

Comment: The page you link states explicitly "*The ISO image is not updated after release*" so you get the release version. Things change quickly nowadays...

Comment: I missed that. Thnaks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `\DeclareFontSeriesDefault` to redeclare the fontseries. I'm doing it in the document only to show the difference. utf8 is the default since more than 2 years, so I removed inputenc:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

abcd \textbf{ABCd}

\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{b}
abcd \textbf{ABCd}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, you're amazing! Your solution works for me.